# What happens to the impinging light if its wavelength is smaller than the absorption band of a semiconductor?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Are all wavelengths absorbed in the semiconductor regardless of material's absorption band?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(electromagnetic_radiation)

Comment: this link has nothing about what I've asked, I'm afraid! I wanted some vivid explanation @Programming Enthusiast

Comment: @kim [Read this first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_band), then if you are still confused you can probably ask a better question that is likely to be given a good answer.